# не понимаю откуда взяли число

Tags: python

[image: откуда взяли число? #фильтр на 4,5,6 биты number &= 0b1110000 я понял ,что это в 2 системе счисления но 1110000 в 2 = 112 в 10]
откуда взяли число?
#фильтр на 4,5,6 биты
number &= 0b1110000
я понял ,что это в 2 системе счисления
но 1110000 в 2 = 112 в 10

Comment: какая разница в какой системе счисления число, вытащить биты из двоичной системы

Answer (score 0):

Возьму для примера число 157 [10] = 10011101 [2]

```
> number = 0b10011101
> number &= 0b1110000
```

Что происходит во втором операторе? Сопоставим разряды чисел и произведём побитовое умножение:

```
10011101
01110000
--------
00010000
```

10000 [2] = 16 [10]. Убедимся в этом:

```
> print(number)
16
```

Операция `&` - это операция побитового `and`, если опустить формальности - побитового умножения:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

В данном случае нам не так важно, что 1110000 [2] = 112 [10].
1110000 - это всего лишь маска для другого числа, позволяющая оставить 4-6 биты и отсечь 0-5 биты.

Answer (score 0):

любое число можно представить в двоичном виде

в двоичном виде число состоит из бит, которые могут быть установлены в `0` или в `1`

биты считаются справа налево

чтобы получить какие-то биты числа надо применить операцию `логическое И`:

```
bits = number & 0b1110000
```

в результате операции у числа все биты кроме `4, 5, 6` будут сброшены в `0`, а 4, 5 и 6 бит останутся теми, что есть

например было число:

```
number = 0b1011101
```

`bits` будет тогда:

```
bits = 0b1010000
```

ну и чтобы найденные биты `101` были в виде числа, то надо избавиться от 0, 1, 2, 3 бит, для чего результат надо сдвинуть вправо на 4 бита

```
bits >>= 4
```

в результате получится

```
bits = 0b101
```

В общем подучите булеву логику и представление чисел в двоичной системе